# How can I write raw image data stored under IntPtr to an Image control in WinUI 3 without extra copies?

Tags: c#, winui-3

I have the following control defined in xaml:

```
<Image x:Name="image" Stretch="None" Width="640" Height="480"/>
```

And I also have some data stored in IntPtr representing a BGRA 640x480 image.
For this example, we can assume that I read the image from a .png file (but it's only one of the ways that I could get image data from):

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap("image.png");
```

I figured that in order to change the source of the Image control, I could use WriteableBitmap. Here is a fully working code that I came up with:

```
int width = 640;
int height = 480;

WriteableBitmap imageBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(width, height);
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap("image.png");

BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(
    new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height),
    ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat
);
               
int size = width * height * 4;
byte[] managedArray = new byte[size];
Marshal.Copy(bitmapData.Scan0, managedArray, 0, size);

bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

imageBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream().Write(managedArray, 0, size);

this.image.Source = imageBitmap;
```

However, the code above makes one extra copy from IntPtr (bitmapData.Scan0) to byte[] (managedArray) just because `imageBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream().Write` does not accept IntPtr as an argument.

Is there a way to do the same without that extra copy?

P.S. In WPF I used to have the following code working well, that didn't require that conversion from IntPtr to byte[]:

```
imageBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(width, height, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Bgra32, null);

Int32Rect rect = new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height);
imageBitmap.WritePixels(rect, bitmapData.Scan0, width * height * 4, stride);

this.image.Source = imageBitmap;
```

I can't figure out how to do the same in WinUI 3

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, there is no way to write raw image data stored under IntPtr to an Image control in WinUI 3 without extra copies. The Bitmap does not accept IntPtr as an argument. You need to use the extra copy to realize it.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT Thank you for your reply. That's quite sad, because this functionality is available in WPF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an `IntPtr` on one side and a `Stream` on the other side, so you need a `Stream` implementation over an `IntPtr`.

You can do this using the [UnmanagedMemoryStream Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.unmanagedmemorystream) and a custom [SafeBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.safebuffer) class:

```
public sealed class IntPtrBuffer : SafeBuffer
{
    public IntPtrBuffer(IntPtr pointer, long byteLength)
        : base(false)
    {
        handle = pointer;
        Initialize((ulong)byteLength);
    }

    protected override bool ReleaseHandle() => true;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap("image.png");

var imageBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);

var bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(
    new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
    ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat
);

var byteLength = bitmapData.Height * bitmapData.Stride;
using var ums = new UnmanagedMemoryStream(new IntPtrBuffer(bitmapData.Scan0, byteLength), 0, byteLength);
using var pixels = imageBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
ums.CopyTo(pixels);

bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

this.image.Source = imageBitmap;
```